# Parse time range from string

Tags: java

I couldn't find an answer to my exact problem so here it goes...Lets say I have a string array with time values that I want to convert to 24-hour time like so:

```
String[] strings = {"12:04 am", "12:04 pm"};
System.out.println("Pick-up Times: ");
for (String i: strings) 
    System.out.println(i);
System.out.println();

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

System.out.println("Converted to 24-Hour format: ");
for (String i: strings) {
    Date date = format.parse(i);        
    Time time = new Time(date.getTime());
    System.out.println(time);
}
```

Output:

> Pick-up Times:
>   12:04 am
>   12:04 pm
>
> Converted to 24-Hour format:
>   00:04:00
>   12:04:00

That works great, but let's say I have a range like 12:00 pm - 12:10 pm for example:

```
String[] strings = {"12:00 pm - 12:10 pm"};
System.out.println("Pick-up Times: ");
for (String i: strings) 
    System.out.println(i);
System.out.println();

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

System.out.println("Converted to 24-Hour format: ");
for (String i: strings) {
    Date date = format.parse(i);        
    Time time = new Time(date.getTime());
    System.out.println(time);
}
```

Here's my output:

> Pick-up Times:
>   12:00 pm - 12:10 pm
>
> Converted to 24-Hour format:
>   12:00:00

I've tried changing SimpleDateFormat like so:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a - hh:mm a");
```

And the result was interesting:

> Pick-up Times:
>   12:00 pm - 12:10 pm
>
> Converted to 24-Hour format:
>   12:10:00

The result I'm looking for is:

> Pick-up Times:
>   12:00 pm - 12:10 pm
>
> Converted to 24-Hour format:
>   12:00:00 - 12:10:00

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect to get here `Date date = format.parse(i)`, then `i` contains two dates in a single String?

Comment: isn't `{"12:00 pm - 12:10 pm"}` just one item? in the first (successful part there is a seperator `,`), this example only has a `-`... just as it looks, you need to split it, then change the format for both items and join them again. Are you sure there is a way to directly convert something like this in one step?

Comment: @DirkReichel no I'm not sure. I didn't think about splitting the string, I'll give that a go. Thanks! Just to clarify my question - some elements of my array are single times like "12:00 pm" while others are a range like "12:00 pm - 12:10 pm" and that's where the parsing issue came into play.

Comment: Well, I hadn't seen Dirk's comments, before writing my answer. I think you can take a look and see if it fits into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the problem is about the range, you can split it up. I'll give you a few lines of code, so you adapt it to your code:

```
String s = {"ABC - aaa - eee - ccc"};
String arr[] = s.split(" - ");
for(String str: arr)
    SYstem.out.println(str);
```

Instead of `s`, you can use your `strings`.

Answer (score 0):

This is OPs solution (extracted from the question):

---

The solution was pretty simple. For anyone that runs into the same problem, this will do the trick:

```
String[] strings = {"12:00 pm - 12:10 pm"};
System.out.println("Pick-up Times: ");
for (String i: strings) 
    System.out.println(i);
System.out.println();

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
int count = 0;

System.out.println("Converted to 24-Hour format: ");
for (String i: strings) {
    String[] test = i.split(" - ");
    for (String j: test)
    {
        Date date = format.parse(j);        
        Time time = new Time(date.getTime());
        System.out.print(time);
        if (count == 0)
            System.out.print(" - ");
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Ouput:

> Pick-up Times:
>   12:00 pm - 12:10 pm
>
> Converted to 24-Hour format:
>   12:00:00 - 12:10:00

Comment: You left out "(I feel dumb)"... ;)

Comment: @java_guy88 Because there is no need to include this, too.